Get all OSM-objects for landuse=meadow
I am using the geofabrik source to download all osm raw-data for Germany. Via osmfilter I extract with keep="landuse=meadow" all the meadow objects.
I understand according to OSM data confusing line and polygon that polygons can consist of lines too. If I try to get these lines for the missing meadow areas out of the geofabrik dataset, I do not get them for the area of interest.
If I use overpass in QGIS all the landuse=meadow areas (polygons AND lines) are downloaded

but for when trying to get the same result via the geofabrik rawdata set not even the lines for the polygons appear.

What am I missing?

I suspect that by far the easiest way with an extract will be to load it into a database using osm2pgsql, and let that decide what is a (multi)polygon or not.  Then just select polygon objects out of the SQL.
https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/ (just the database part) covers the first bit, then:
gis=> select count(*) from planet_osm_polygon where landuse = 'meadow';
 count
-------
 10855
(1 row)

Also you might want to look in the OSM data itself to see what things that you consider a "meadow" are actually tagged as.  There may be other keys and values that you ought to consider.
